# Is it possible in to only run tests in a certain _directory_ via command line (in Android Studio/Gradle)?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

I have a need to separate running "unit tests" from more specifically named unit tests called "requirements tests". Directory structure like:

```
src
 |__main\
 |__test\
 |__testRequirements\
```

I added a separate `srcSet` so I can run these all together no problem.

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/testRequirements/java']
  }
}
```

But, I need to be able to run ONLY the `testRequirements` by command so I can have ONLY them run in their own CI flow. I see that I can target them specifically by using the filtering by package/class/method a la:

```
./gradlew test --tests *RequirementsTest
```

But that relies on humans appending the same string to every class name.

---

I played around a little with creating a new flavor just for `requirements` so I could access with a command `./gradlew testRequirementsDebugUnitTest` but that would run both the requirements AND all my other unit tests

Comment: Just define a `TestSuite` and then run that instead.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Hmm, it looks like using a `TestSuite` I'd have to manually add all the test classes to the suite?